# Show All Duplicate Records QUERY

Tags: sql

What is the query that will show all the records that have multiple names?

For example.

Table 1:

```
| ID | Name    | Age   | Email           |
+----+---------+-------+-----------------+
| 1  | Mike    | 12    | mike@gmail.com  |
| 2  | Mon     | 10    | mon@gmail.com   |
| 3  | Peter   | 12    | pet@gmail.com   |
| 4  | Mike    | 13    | mike12@gmail.com|
```

Desired result:

```
| ID | Name    | Age   | Email           |
+----+---------+-------+-----------------+
| 1  | Mike    | 12    | mike@gmail.com  |
| 4  | Mike    | 13    | mike12@gmail.com|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and join result to origin table

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM myTable t1

JOIN

  (SELECT Name
   FROM myTable
   GROUP BY Name
   HAVING COUNT(Name) > 1) t2

ON t1.Name = t2.Name
```

Comment: what is the use of t1 and t2? is it for alias?

Comment: Yes, aliases make queries more readable.

Answer (score 2):

One option, using `COUNT()` as an analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Name) cnt
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT ID, Name, Age, Email
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Comment: I would suggest a CTE like this answer. It will return all duplicate rows with a count of how many. My only change would to maybe put "SELECT COUNT(*), t.*" instead - just personal preference to see first how many duplicates there are.

Comment: Also, make sure you mark this as the answer if it solves your problem!